# Add class on drop event for image puzzle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-draggable

Hey guys i am using Django templeting system and bootstrap for a project where i have a reuirement of jquery image drag and drop. I dont have any knowledge of jquery or javascript.
So far i have implemented the image drag and drop but now i want to add a class on drop event.

Here in my requirement i have a image cut out in five pieces. Each pieces are stored in one container. user can drag a piece to drop it in another container to complete the image. but when i am droping it in another container all the images are aligned vertically instead of geeting joined to previous piece.

so i have decided to add a class on drop event which can add style="position:absolute; property to image.

I hope u have understood my problem. i know this is a nub question but please help we with code

Here i have added it on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/binit/JnYB9/ So that you can play around help me

**code**

---

```
<script>
$(function() {

$( "#sortable1" ).sortable({
connectWith: "div"
});

$( "#sortable2" ).sortable({
connectWith: "div"

 });

$( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).disableSelection();
 });
</script>

{% endblock headercontent %}


{% block content %}

<div class="row-fluid" >
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="span1"></div>
        <div id="sortable1" class="well sidebar-nav sidebar-nav-fixed span11">
            <legend>Collect Coupon parts</legend>
            1st part
            <img class="ui-state-highlight" src="{% static 'images/demo/north.png' %}" >
            2nd part
            <img class="ui-state-highlight" src="{% static 'images/demo/south.png' %}" >
            3rd part
            <img class="ui-state-highlight" src="{% static 'images/demo/east.png' %}" >
            4th part
            <img class="ui-state-highlight" src="{% static 'images/demo/west.png' %}" >
            5th part
            <img class="ui-state-highlight" src="{% static 'images/demo/center.png' %}"  >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sortable2" class=" well sidebar-nav sidebar-nav-fixed span8">

        <legend>Canvas section</legend>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several points:

- When you're asking a client-side Javascript question, it would be best not to muddy the waters with your server-side markup.  So non-HTML templates like this should probably either be expanded (from, say, View Source) or removed:

  ```
   {% extends "dashboard.html" %}

   {% block headercontent %}
  ```
- Your code already has an example of adding a class on drop (at least if I'm guessing correctly about the jQuery drag-and-drop; it's been a long time) in this block.

  ```
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
      $( this )
          .addClass( "fullbowl" )
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          .find( "div" )
          .html( "" );
  ```

  So you can either duplicate this if it's a different group of sortables you want to style and add a different class, add a second `addClass('something')` call to this one -- which would be fine -- or change the CSS for `fullbowl` to include your new properties.  Lots of options.

### Update

With your new Fiddle, it's easier to test, and it becomes straightforward to notice that you're not using an event of JQuery UI's `sortable` API, but one from `droppable`.  If you used `stop`, from `sortable`, it works fine:

```
$( "#sortable2" ).sortable({
    connectWith: "div",
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.item.addClass( "fullbowl" )
    }
});
```

You can see it in action on **[my fork of your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/Z79pF/)**.

Comment: Actually its not working. I have edited the question as you said

Comment: What's not working; the addClass call?  And I still see what I assume are Django templates in there...  :-)

Comment: In the **[API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop) for the `drop` event, there is no mention of what `this` is bound to.  But the second parameter, `ui`, has a reference to the draggable object, so perhaps instead of `$(this).addClass("fullbowl")...` you could do `ui.draggable.addClass("fullbowl")...`

Comment: can u edit my current code because any how that thing dose not work so i have removed that completely.

Comment: No, but I'd suggest you post a JSFiddle, JSBin, Plunkr, codepen, or other sandboxed version to show the issue you're having.  People might be able to help if they could play around with it.

Comment: If i have that few lines in my code my drag and drop is also not working that why i have removed that

Comment: I have added the JSFiddle link in my question

Comment: what changes i need to do if i want to add different class on drop of different image by assiging id to each image